# Syntax error: Operator expected (SWI Prolog)

Tags: prolog, syntax-error

I'm getting the issue: Syntax error: Operator expected

This is my code

```
reduceBy1(Input,Output) :-
    (Input > 0 -> Output = Input - 1).
```

What am I doing wrong? The error points towards the "."

Comment: Try this, did not check. Change `Output = Input - 1` to `Output is Input - 1`. HTH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use is instead of =.

```
reduceBy1(Input,Output) :-
    (Input > 0 -> Output is Input - 1). 

?-reduceBy1(5,O).
O = 4
```